# can we Pass MethodName In TestNG DataProviders

Tags: testng, dataprovider, utility

I want to use one class from different package in different package where `Dataprovider` method is using.

E.g.

My First Package name is : `Framework Utilities`

My Second Package name is : `Framework Testcases`

I want to use `@DataProvider` for `Framework Testcases` package but for that i want to use method which is available in the `Framework Utilities` package.

Can you please help me for the solution as it is very important

Answer (score 0):

Dataprovider takes Method as an argument, which you can use to get package and other info. So you can declare it on the declaration and use to do your conditional checks.

eg.

```
@DataProvider(name = "testDataProvider2")
    public Object[][] testDataProvider2(Method method) {
        System.out.println(method.getDeclaringClass());...
```